# Getting the category title / description returns first matching post?

Tags: categories, theme-development

I'm working on a `template-part` called `heading` which displays the page heading and an optional subtitle underneath. I have it working on pages, but on archive pages like our blog or product category pages, it returns the first matching post title.

### Here's the code:

```php
$id = get_the_ID();
$heading = get_the_title();
$sub_heading = get_field('sub_heading', $id);


if (is_home() || is_category()) {
    $heading = get_the_title(12);
    $sub_heading = 'Learn, Modify, Create.';
} else if (is_404()) {
    $heading = '404';
    $sub_heading = "Well, this is awkward.";
} else if (is_shop()) {
    $heading = 'SHOP';
    $sub_heading = "Explore our complete product offering here";
} else if (is_product_category()) {
    $sub_heading = category_description();
}

?>

<div class="page-heading-section-wrapper">

    <div class="page-heading-section">

        <h1 class="main-heading"><?php echo $heading; ?> </h1>

        <?php if ($sub_heading) {
            echo '<h2 class="sub-heading">' . $sub_heading . '</h2>';
        }; ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

### Example:

If I had a product category of "Balloons" and my products within it were "Birthday", "Holiday" etc, the title on the archive page would be "Birthday". The **category description** seems to work fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there's no code showing how the template is being called in context, can you edit that into your question?

Answer (score 1):

For categories/taxonomies you can use `get_queried_object` to get the current category. From there you can easily get the name. So from your example:

```
if ( is_category() ) {
    $cat = get_queried_object();
    $heading = $cat->name;
}
```

Comment: So I was just able to fix it using `get_the_archive_title()`. Is there a benefit to your way?

Comment: This way won’t work. `get_the_title()` cannot get archive titles.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes, you are right! My answer was too fast. I edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it out!